# Debugger is not working in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: xcode6.3.1

Since Xcode 6.3.1, with a Swift project (not Obj-C), if the name of the project folder contains one or more / slashes such as a date i.e SomeApp04/05/15 the debugger does not work correctly for me.  It ignores (goes right past) breakpoints without stopping.  Remove the slashes in the name of the project folder and the debugger works correctly.

Anyone else experienced this lack of function of the debugger?